# Different Typescript inference management between vscode and monaco-editor

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, type-inference, monaco-editor

I just made a complex function that take 3 arguments : name, types and method.
This function stores a method in a store. It infer the return type of the third agument from the second one.

**addMethod.d.ts**

```js
interface SimplifiedTypeMap {
  string: string;
  number: number;
  boolean: boolean;
}

type GlobalMethodAdd = <T extends keyof SimplifiedTypeMap>(
  name: string,
  types: T[],
  method: () => SimplifiedTypeMap[T]
) => void;

interface MethodStore {
  [name: string]: {
    types: (keyof SimplifiedTypeMap)[];
    method: () => SimplifiedTypeMap[keyof SimplifiedTypeMap];
  };
}
```

Thanks to typescript engine, the return type of the last argument (method) is inferred from the items in the second argument (types) and int forces the user of the function to write a method with a specific return type

**addMethod.ts**

```js
import { random } from "lodash-es";

export const methodStorage: MethodStore = {};

const addMethod: GlobalMethodAdd = (name, types, method) => {
  methodStorage[name] = { types, method };
};

addMethod("test", ["string", "number"], () =>
  random(1, true) > 0.5 ? "abcd" : 1234
);
```

When i'm using the addMethod function on Visual-Studio Code or Codesandbox, the return type of the third argument is well known but not on monaco-editor :

**visual studio code**
[image]

**codesandbox editor**
[image]

**(FAILING) monaco editor**
[image]

[Here is my example in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-brattain-ly11j)

=========================================================================

**EDIT**
I found out that it's the usage of noLib compiler option that makes that happen.

```js
reactMonaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
  target: reactMonaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.ES5,
  noLib: true,
  allowNonTsExtensions: true,
  checkJs: true,
});
```

Is there a way to avoid es5 libs autocompletion while keeping inference working properly?

Comment: Commenting noLib did the trick for me.

Answer (score 6):

## TL;DR

Until Monaco Editor implements a proper solution, just use `monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.addExtraLib(YOUR_CUSTOM_LIBRARY,"defaultLib:lib.es6.d.ts")` and don't bother with `setCompilerOptions` at all. You can create your own custom lib by combining the parts you want from https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/tree/master/lib.

## Long version

I'm using monaco editor as well and had the same issue. After looking around a bit at the monaco source code, I think I found a solution (workaround?) that does not require modifying the source code of monaco editor.

First of all, let's take a look at the current behavior. Monaco Editor uses a so-called [LanguageServiceHost](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/454a3a0b0fd1d197e1f970e40e49fc7b29741d47/src/services/types.ts#L203) to implement TypeScript related functionality, see also [Using the Language Service API](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Using-the-Language-Service-API)
:

> It [the language host] abstracts all interactions between the language service and the external world. The language service host defers managing, monitoring and maintaining input files to the host.

The TypeScript language host for Monaco editor is part of the [microsoft/monaco-typescript](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-typescript) repository and can be found in [tsWorker.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-typescript/blob/master/src/tsWorker.ts#L23).

Now, if we take a look at the source code, we find that only [two library files](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-typescript/blob/master/src/tsWorker.ts#L13) are [currently supported](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-typescript/blob/master/src/tsWorker.ts#L116) by Monaco Editor:

- lib.d.ts ([source code](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts))
- lib.es6.d.ts ([source code](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts))

`lib.d.ts` is used when the [compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) [target](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.typescript.compileroptions.html#target) is set to [ES5](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/enums/monaco.languages.typescript.scripttarget.html#es5), otherwise `lib.es6.d.ts` is used. Some more debugging reveals that no matter what we set for the [lib](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.typescript.compileroptions.html#lib) option, one of these both files is used as the library. As you mention, we could use the [noLib](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.typescript.compileroptions.html#nolib) option, but this results in other side effects such as type inference not working correctly anymore.

---

So now I had the idea that most of the time, you don't want no library, but a different library. The DOM specific parts  (which I presume you don't want) are in  [lib.dom.d.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts), which is included by [lib.d.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts). 
Usually, it's a good idea to add at least [lib.es5.d.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es5.d.ts), which contains the types for JavaScript basics such as `Object`, `Function` or `Number`; or perhaps [lib.es2015.d.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es2015.d.ts), which contains `Symbol`, new array methods and more. So the question becomes: How do we make Monaco Editor use a custom - possibly empty - library?

In `monaco-typescript`, the library source code is hard-coded in the file [lib.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-typescript/blob/master/src/lib/lib.ts). So if we were using a bundler such as webpack, we could just replace that file with our own version that exports a constant `lib_dts` or `lib_es6_dts` with the library we want to use. This option may not always be possible, and modifying the source code of a library is not a good idea anyway.

But if we take another look at `tsWorker.ts` and [how it retrieves the content for a given file name](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-typescript/blob/master/src/tsWorker.ts#L71), another solution (workaround?) presents itself: If we [add an extra lib](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.typescript.languageservicedefaults.html#addextralib) with a specific name, that extra lib will be used instead of the built-in libraries.

- for `lib.d.ts`, use the file name `defaultLib:lib.d.ts`
- for `lib.es6.d.ts`, use the file name `defaultLib:lib.es6.d.ts`

To summarize, here's an example with your code that can be run on the [Monaco Editor playground](https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/playground.html). Please note that this sets the target to `ES5` (as in your example), but we could also not modify the compiler options at all and just use `lib.es6.d.ts` when adding the extra lib.

```js
const code = `
interface SimplifiedTypeMap {
    string: string;
    number: number;
    boolean: boolean;
}

type GlobalMethodAdd = <T extends keyof SimplifiedTypeMap>(
    name: string,
    types: T[],
    method: () => SimplifiedTypeMap[T]
) => void;

interface MethodStore {
    [name: string]: {
        types: (keyof SimplifiedTypeMap)[];
        method: () => SimplifiedTypeMap[keyof SimplifiedTypeMap];
    };
}

export const methodStorage: MethodStore = {};

const addMethod: GlobalMethodAdd = (name, types, method) => {
    methodStorage[name] = { types, method };
};

// Try hovering over addMethod, type inferrence works correctly
addMethod("test", ["string", "number"], () =>
    1 > 0.5 ? "abcd" : 1234
);

// No DOM library loaded, so this gives an error
new HTMLAnchorElement();    
`;

async function setup() {
    const response = await fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/TypeScript/master/lib/lib.es5.d.ts");
    const libes5 = await response.text();

    monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.setCompilerOptions({
        allowNonTsExtensions: true,
        target: monaco.languages.typescript.ScriptTarget.ES5,
    });

    // Use "lib.custom.d.ts" for ES5, and "defaultLib:lib.es6.d.ts" for ESNext (the default)
    monaco.languages.typescript.typescriptDefaults.addExtraLib(
        libes5,
        "defaultLib:lib.d.ts"
    );

    monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("container"), {
        value: code,
        language: "typescript"
    });
}

setup();
```

Also, here's a [modified version of your Code Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-brook-t4q6g).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. You just gave me exactly what i needed!